# Which version of automapper is compatible with .Net Framework 4.8?

Tags: automapper

I'm faced with upgrading a project in production to a more recent .net framework and it is looking like Automapper cuts of support at 4.6.1?  And that is out of support at the end of August 2022.

Is there a version of Automapper compatible with .net 4.8?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 is backward compatible to 4.6.1, possibly earlier too. While not tried, I guess it should just work. It may not take advantage of the new features but the existing thing should run like before.

Answer (score 20):

Version 10.1.1 works with my .net 4.8.

It was an unpleasant discovery to find I was expected to somehow turn a winforms project into a post .net 4.8 framework as it's not a simple select new framework thing to do. So I reverted to the latest one that still has .net 4.6.1 and it's fine.

Comment: Yeah my issue with that would be Microsoft ends support for 4.6 on 4/26/2022

Comment: It works with 4.8 - which is what my project uses.

Answer (score 4):

The last version compatible with .Net Framework is 10.1.1.

Since AutoMapper 11.0 was released, it no longer supports the .Net Framework.

[AutoMapper 11.0.0 released](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-11-0-0-released/)

[AutoMapper now targets .Net Standard 2.1 and doesn’t work on .Net Framework](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html)